# Change creation time of files (RPM) from download time to build time

Tags: rpm, date, timestamps, touch

I am going to create my own internal repository service via `createrepo` and want to provide an Java repository as well.

Downloading the JRE and JDK packages automatically and as [described at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49780226/6771046) leaves me with files which have a timestamp from the time they were downloaded. The creation time of the files is set to the runtime of the download script.

For further processing I like to have the timestamps set to the build time of the RPM package (... so that I can query them via `ls -al`, `ll`, `--full-time`, etc.).

How to change creation time of files (RPM) from download time to build time automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I've found that I can query the RPM build time via `rpm -qip`.

```bash
BUILDTIME=$(rpm -qip --nosignature ${FILENAME} | grep -i "Build Date  : " | sed -e 's/Build Date  : //g')
echo ${BUILDTIME}
```

The `date` command can reformat the given date and time string

```bash
TIMESTAMP=$(date --date="${BUILDTIME}" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
echo ${TIMESTAMP}
```

so that it could be later used with the `touch` command.

```
touch -m -a -t ${TIMESTAMP} ${FILENAME}
```

By iterating over all files within a specific directory it is possible to list all creation times of all packages contained and modify it automatically.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for FILENAME in *.rpm; do

    echo ${FILENAME}

    BUILDTIME=$(rpm -qip --nosignature ${FILENAME} | grep -i "Build Date  : " | sed -e 's/Build Date  : //g')
    echo ${BUILDTIME}

    TIMESTAMP=$(date --date="${BUILDTIME}" "+%Y%m%d%H%M")
    echo ${TIMESTAMP}

    touch -m -a -t ${TIMESTAMP} ${FILENAME}

done
```

Comment: Or you can use `rpm --qf ...` to extract only the headers you care about: `touch "$PACKAGE" -d"$(rpm -qp "$PACKAGE" --qf "%{BUILDTIME:date}\n")"`

Comment: Just tested with `rpm -qp "${FILENAME}" --qf "%{BUILDTIME:date}\n")"` and found it more elegant. Thanks for the hint and +1.